# Помогите расшифровать файл из mmo игры с расширением *.ten предполагаю что он содержит IP и Порт

Tags: файлы

Имеются 2 файла с расширение *.ten один ServerList.ten и UpdateURL.ten они содержат я так понял первый IP и Порт, а второй веб адрес но они зашифрованы ка то помогите расшифровать данные два файлы.

[файл ServerList.ten](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mgRlrHHuSEt_ptK2OZpPNxvLFxuxF9qe/view?usp=sharing)

[файл UpdateUrl.ten](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17N-BF2T-oEto0uLChjsOIgIFJbecahUw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, это файл для ***TeeChart for .NET*** ([пруф](https://www.file-extension.info/ru/format/ten)). Если что, [вот](https://www.steema.com/product/net) официальный сайт, где можно скачать данное приложение

Comment: я до этого пробывал это программа не относится к даному файлу

Comment: этот файл написан в мне не известной шифровке просто й пример написать .cs зашифровать его в RSA и переименовать в *.ten что бы раскодировать надо просто взять это файл и обратно с RSA в обыкновенный текст раскодить на в данном случаее мне не известен метод шифровки. Так что данная программа была проверена на возможный способ открытия но не помогло.